# Visual Studio 2019 Preview Remote Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017, I run the remote debugger server (MSVSMON) on my local machine as an administrator so that I can attach the debugger to IIS without Visual Studio needing to run as an administrator.

When running Visual Studio 2019 Preview, the attach the debugger dialog doesn't seem to detect the MSVSMON process and so can't connect.

Is there a new version of MSVCMON?
I've tried using Bing / Google with no luck.
Is it just a bug in 2019 that it can't detect but it should?

Any suggestions how I can resolve this would be appreciated. This is a critical part of my workflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it. They haven't published a package for the current preview but the debugger is included in the standard install at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe

Comment: Remote Tools for VS 2019 RC can be found here:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=remote+tools#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Direct access to the VS2019 tools download page: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202019&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2019 finally got an Installer Package on the Download-Site of Visual Studio: [Visual Studio Remote Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/downloads/?q=remote%20tools)

This package should be preferred if you need the Windows Service for Debugging another machine.

Answer (score 5):

The link above did not work for me. Downloaded it now from the following page:

[Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202019)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, no link worked for me as they all linked me to a download page for `Visual Studio 2022`.
If you guys are searching for the **msvsmon.exe** files, I found them at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger
```

Both for `x64` and `x86`